# Signing for "appnameTest" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'appnameTest')

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

When I try to run fresh installed **React native** project in Xcode I'm getting this error.

Though I have added a developer account for signing. 
My Xcode version is **10.0 (10A255)**

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes i did, i have added in the answer section @BradW

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First open your project in the Xcode.

Then select the project and click on this section.

[image]

After that click on the test file

[image]

And finally add your Signing

[image]